# What is the purpose of having 2 endian representations?

Tags: endianness

I was wondering what the purpose of having 2 different endian representations is. I get the difference between the 2, how to store values, by why have 2 of them?

Comment: It's all about history. Read e.g. [this](http://books.google.pl/books?id=SA92uQqTB-AC&pg=PA29&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) to find out more.

Comment: There are more than two endiannesses. The middle-endian [PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11) is still in use in a few places, notably nuclear power plants.

Comment: What's the point of driving on different sides of the road?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is not a standard or a programming language, it's a hardware design people came up with. Suppose you've implemented a memory, and wanted to store data in it. The data spans over two bytes. Which byte will you put in the first (low) address? The low part of the data or the high part? You can bet that whenever there are options, there would be that amount of implementations. :-)